# Can NiFi variable registry be updated on the fly?

Tags: environment-variables, apache-nifi, kubernetes-helm

If I'm using Helm to deploy NiFi, is there a way to update the variable registry on the fly (without interrupting the current flow). Right now it seems NiFi has to be brought down and redeployed in order for changes to the variable registry to take place.

The response to a similar question posed 3 years ago states, "the current variable registry capability requires a restart and cannot be updated on the fly.":  [How to update variable.registry.properties in Nifi on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42025852/how-to-update-variable-registry-properties-in-nifi-on-the-fly)

That answer, coupled with the fact that NiFi is now using/supporting Parameters, leads me to believe the answer to my question is no. I also haven't found any documentation online that answers the question. Could use some guidance if anyone has found a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The file-based variable registry has not changed since the previous answer you referenced, and it still requires a restart.

There are process-group variables that can be set through the UI/REST API, and these will automatically restart components that reference them.

Then there are parameters which should be preferred over variables, and they work similar in that modifying a parameter context will restart referencing components.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Bryan. By "process-group variables that can be set through the REST API", do you mean something like this can be employed?: stackoverflow.com/questions/52010827/… I was thinking maybe nipyapi could help if I use "nipyapi.canvas.update_variable_registry". I found it leveraged here (pierrevillard.com/tag/flow), but I haven't attempted it yet. Thoughts?